# Указание пути к папке ресурсов в веб-проекте?

Tags: java, java-ee, файлы, path

Добрый день!

Собственно вопрос, как указать путь к папке ресурсов, которая располагается в корне проекта?

Вот сама структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как указываю путь:

```
File fileDist = new File("patient/"+patient.getId()+".jpg"); 
LOG.trace("Path file: "+fileDist.getAbsolutePath());
```

В лог-журнале пишет путь не к проекту, а к папке, где установлен eclipse.

В папку build копируются подпапки папки resource: file, font, ...
Прописываю относительный путь к ним - patient/"+patient.getId()+".jpg, но все так же.

Информация лог-журнала:

```
[TRACE] InsertNewPatient(execute):106 - Path fileUp: C:\Users\Роман\Pictures\SpotBright\7000000000257422_1080x1920.jpg
[TRACE] InsertNewPatient(execute):107 - Path fileDist: C:\Program Files\eclipse-jee-mars-2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\patient\25.jpg
[TRACE] InsertNewPatient(execute):116 - Request parameter: foto --> null
```

Буду рад любому совету!

Comment: собираете в jar или war ? resources копируется в папку build?

Comment: проект запускаю через eclipse, resources в папку build не копируются

Comment: А что это за проект такой? это для веба или обычное для desktop? Интересуюсь потому что, от типа приложения зависит способ получения внешних ресурсов.

Comment: это проект для веба

Comment: дополнен вопрос

Comment: Как я понимаю, у вас все это должно собираться в war архив и деплоиться на сервер приложений. Следовательно, если эти ресурсы не обновляются динамически их нужно паковать в архив. Настройте сборку в maven или gradle для этого. Далее, будет все очень просто, this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("../resources/patient/"+patient.getId()+".jpg");

Comment: данные ресурсы обновляются, пользователь добавляет изображения

Comment: можно вот так получить путь до папки с java классами, а потом уже достучаться до папке с ресурсами final File f = new File(Solution.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообщем разобрался со своим вопросом:

При развертывании приложения на сервере, соответственно путь к приложению меняется, поэтому, когда указываю путь к папке ресурс, то:

```
//получаем абсолютный путь к папке с приложением
String appPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("");
//указываю путь к директории, куда хочу сохранить файл
String savePath = appPath + File.separator + "resources\\patient\\"+patient.getId()+".jpg";
//создаю директорию, если она не существует
File fileSaveDir = new File(savePath);
    if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) {
        fileSaveDir.mkdir();
    }
```

Лог-журнал:

```
[TRACE] InsertNewPatient(execute):103 - Absolute path to application:     D:\EPAM\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4\wtpwebapps\SummaryTask4
[TRACE] InsertNewPatient(execute):105 - Save path: D:\EPAM\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4\wtpwebapps\SummaryTask4\resources\patient
[TRACE] InsertNewPatient(execute):111 - file moved to directory img
[TRACE] InsertNewPatient(execute):128 - Request parameter: foto --> D:\EPAM\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4\wtpwebapps\SummaryTask4\resources\patient\39.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Если на ваш вопрос взглянуть под другим углом? Предположим у вас есть файлы локализации которые вы используете на своих страницах для правильного отображения надписей на нужном языке, они у вас конечно называются одинаково, только с разными окончаниями _en_US и _ru_RU - local_en_US.properties и local_ru_RU.properties. 
Для пользования на страницах в виде -

```html
<p:outputLabel > #{myprop['key1']}</p:outputLabel>
```

Располагаются они строго в директории src/main/resources 
Для того чтоб контейнер сам читал ваши файлы .properties вы конечно поместите файл faces-config.xml в корень директории WEB-INF -

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2"
              xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
              
    <application>
      <locale-config>
         <default-locale>ru_RU</default-locale>
         <supported-locale>en_US</supported-locale>
      </locale-config>
      
      <resource-bundle>
         <base-name>local</base-name>
         <var>myprop</var>
      </resource-bundle>
      
   </application>
</faces-config>
```

Да, теперь в файле faces-config.xml вы описали resource-bundle, указали под каким именем вы его будете использовать на .xhtml страничке - myprop. И контейнер теперь сам подхватывает значение из нужного файла локализации и все круто, мы не забиваем в код текста, а вынесли их в отдельные файлы да еще и с переводом!
Возвращаемся к вашему вопросу -

> Указание пути к папке ресурсов в веб-проекте?

Ответ - в описанном мной случае, это и не нужно, контейнер и так знает где они лежат) И для того чтоб в коде взять одно из значений описанные в наших  .properties надо сделать следующее -

```js
ServletRequest request = .....
Locale locale = request.getLocale();
ResourceBundle bundle1 = ResourceBundle.getBundle("local", locale);
log.info("key1- " + bundle1.getString("key1"));
```

первым аргументом getBoundle() вы дали название вашего файла .properties, только без окончания _ru_RU или _en_US, окончание а значит и сам файл выберет контейнер исходя из локали которую вы передали вторым аргументом.
вывод в косоль будет -

```html
key1- тоЧтоВыНаписалиВФайл
```

На том языке которым пользуется пользователь,  чей request вы взяли ;)